# howto logging attribute add/modify in openldap

Tags: openldap, audit

I want to remain log in openldap for audit.
So i add olcAuditlogConfig. But olcAuditlogConfig remain the ldapadd,ldapmodify,ldapdelete... cmd.

we used phpldapadmin, not log remain.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the auditlog overlay, there is also an overlay that is called accesslog. You can find more about it under `man 5 slapo-accesslog`, under http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/accesslog.html or 
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Access%20Logging

It is a little harder to setup than auditlog because you need to setup another database in your cn=config (or backend config) where this overlay can write into; however, you get very detailed logs in return.

Using cn=config your overlay could for example look like this:

`dn: olcOverlay=accesslog,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAccessLogConfig
olcOverlay: accesslog
olcAccessLogDB: cn=accesslog
olcAccessLogOps: reads
olcAccessLogPurge: 07+00:00 01+00:00
olcAccessLogSuccess: TRUE`

This overlay is logging into the DIT `cn=accesslog`, which I created like this:

`dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
olcSuffix: cn=accesslog
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config
olcDbIndex: default eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart`

Remember to create the directory specified in `olcDbDirectory` and give your openLDAP system user write access beforehands!

Comment: thanks your advices.

i solved problem. i mistake set path

dn: olcOverlay=auditlog,olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
  →
dn: olcOverlay=auditlog,olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config

Comment: Good to see you made it! Would you mind to post this as a separate answer and to mark it as the solutiom? This way the question shows up as answered :)